# Inequality in Frankl's conjecture

Tags: combinatorics, conjectures

For the minimal counter-example to union closed sets conjecture, we have the lower bound $\mid$$\mathcal{A}$$\mid$ $\geq$ $4q-1$ ($\mathcal{A}$ denotes the minimal counter-example family, $q$ denotes the number of elements in $\cup$$\mathcal{A}$). Is there any better lower bound? Is there any research/development happening towards this direction?

Comment: I know what Frankl';s conjecture is. It says that, if $\mathcal F$ ils a nonempty finite collection of nonempty finite sets which is closed under binary union ($A,B\in\mathcal F\implies A\cup B\in\mathcal F$) and if no point is in more than $d$ of the sets, then $|\mathcal F|\le2d-1.$ Right? But I'm afraid I don't recall what the letters $\mathcal A$ and $q$ stand for. Can you please remind me?

Comment: Hi bof, edited the question to include the definitions.

Comment: Also you may refer to http://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/47/ajc_v47_p265.pdf for more information on this inequality.

Comment: Among the various equivalent formulations of Frankl's conjecture there are versions with $\emptyset\in\mathcal A$ and versions with $\emptyset\notin\mathcal A.$ Although the formulations are equivalent, it's hard to tell exactly what "size of a minimal counterexample" means without knowing whether $\emptyset$ is counted or not. Personally, I think it would be simplest to just ***state*** Frankl's conjecture in the form you're referring to, and I can see no good reason to avoid stating it. It's not that long.

Comment: @bof the given bound does not depend on $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$ or $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{A}$.

Answer (score 0):

There is [this](https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/72/ajc_v72_p350.pdf) recent paper that gives a better bound of:
$$\mid\mathcal{A}\mid \geq 4q+1$$